# Unable to access aria-label attribute in Chrome extension for Facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, html, google-chrome-extension

I've looked everywhere but haven't found a solution to my problem.

I'm creating a Chrome extension that needs to access the aria-label attribute of a link element on a Facebook page.  For some reason, it always returns undefined.  Here's the element (sorry about the length):

```
<a class="UFICommentLikeButton" role="button" rel="dialog" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-alignh="center" ajaxify="/ajax/browser/dialog/likes?id=something" href="/browse/likes?id=something" data-reactid=".r[1yfhw].[1][4][1]{comment}.[0].{right}.[0].{left}.[0].[3].[4]" aria-label="X and Y like this." id="js_13" tabindex="0"><i class="UFICommentLikeIcon" data-reactid=".r[1yfhw].[1][4][1]{comment}.[0].{right}.[0].{left}.[0].[3].[4].[0]"></i><span data-reactid=".r[1yfhw].[1][4][1]{comment}.[0].{right}.[0].{left}.[0].[3].[4].[1]">2</span></a>
```

And here's my attempt to create an alert for the class and aria-label attributes of the element, resulting in "class: UFICommentLikeButton" and "aria-label: undefined":

```
$(a.UFICommentLikeButton).each(function() {
    window.alert("class: " + $(this).attr("class"));
    window.alert("aria-label: " + $(this).attr("aria-label"));
});
```

The frustrating thing is that I can get aria-label with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JeQ9K/1/

Any ideas why I wouldn't be able to access aria-label on a Facebook page?

Comment: Could it be caused by the jQuery version you are using?
The jsFiddle just uses DOM APIs, which of course you could do in your extension as well.

Comment: It actually randomly started working on its own, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, to fix I simply had to change:

```
$(this).attr("aria-label"));
```

to

```
$(this).getAttribute("aria-label"));
```

and it pulled the value for me.  Thought that I would add my two cents for anyone else that may run into this problem.